# MySQL no affected rows upon UPDATE when value not changed

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, rows-affected

MySQL with PHP, trying to update a row:

```
$dbQuery = 'UPDATE UserTable SET Age=25 WHERE Id=3';
$result = mysqli_query($dbLink, $dbQuery);
if ($result === FALSE) {
  // Take care of error
}
else {
  $numAffectedRows = mysqli_affected_rows($dbLink);
}
```

I get zero $numAffectedRows in two **different** cases:
 1. When there is no user row with Id=3
 2. When there is a user row with Id=3 but Age was already 25 before

Is there a way I can **distinguish** between the two cases? (apart from reading the row before and manually check the value before updating)

Comment: Your not affecting a row in either case, this seems like a strange question, surely your updating via a form which means the user exists to begin with and you know their ID?

Comment: A standard update query sent from a form if coded right will return either a success message or an error message, in your success message you will get the affected rows ie. 1. In your error message you could also return the affected rows ie.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-affected-rows.html), you can change the behaviour of affected_rows by passing the MYSQLI_CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS flags while connecting using [mysql_real_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php).

In this case, mysql_affected_rows returns the number of rows matched by the WHERE condition, not the number of updated rows.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible with *just one query*.
I would go for `INSERT INTO..ON DUPLICATE` approach.

```
$dbQuery = "INSERT INTO UserTable (Id,Age) VALUES('3','25') ON DUPLICATE KEY 
            UPDATE Id='3',Age='25'";
$result = mysql_query($dbQuery);
if ($result === FALSE) {
   // Take care of error
}
else {
   $numAffectedRows = mysql_affected_rows();
   // $numAffectedRows = 0  => row exist
   // $numAffectedRows = >0 => row added with Id,Age specified
}
```